# java: best practice to accessing objects in another test

Tags: java, junit

I have two separate junit test .java files. it has the following convention below

```
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Test (groups = "integration")
public class myOneIntegrationTest {
    @BeforeMethod
    @SneakyThrows
    public void beforeMethod() {...}

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod() {...}

    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    public void testOne() {...}
```

the test file is localized so that it is testing for one object

I need a test for a functionality that requires an object created in beforeMethod in javaOne.java and another object created in beforeMethod of javaTwo.java

i really dont want to copy-paste beforeMethod from each java files. Is it possible to just import it and test it in javaThree.java?

Comment: You can make a static helper method somewhere in your test source tree and call that from both tests's `beforeMethod`.

Comment: Or use inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [creational pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern) which is derived from the `factory pattern` called [`Object Mother`](https://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/object-mother/). 
Martin Fowler wrote an [Article in 2006](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ObjectMother.html) about it with further readings.

In my opinion this is well suited for testing but you really should replace any boiler plate code with one generated through Lombok (e.g. [@Builder](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder)).